# Calculating Coordinated Mars Time

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to follow this tutorial step-by-step: https://jtauber.github.io/mars-clock/  but getting wildly inaccurate results. I had to modify step one to get the correct result but got stuck in step two as it always gives me an inaccurate, rounded result.

```
NSInteger millis = ( [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000 );
NSLog(@"millis: %ld", (long)millis);

CGFloat JDUT = ( 2440587.5000 + (millis / 86400000) );
NSLog(@"JDUT: %f", JDUT);
```

As you can see, I had to multiply timeIntervalSince1970 by one thousand to get the correct number, but I cannot get a correct JDUT. It is supposed to be a something like this at the time I am writing this: **2,458,840.37654** but my result is **2,458,839.500000**. I assume it is number conversion problem, but I cannot figure out where I did go wrong.

Your help is much appreciated!

p.s.: Notice that I use Objective-C; I do not understand swift unfortunately!

p.s.2.: If you could save me some time and give me pointers to at least some of the later steps that would be very kind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `millis` must be of type `CGFloat` to keep the decimals

```
CGFloat millis = ( [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000 );
NSLog(@"millis: %ld", (long)millis);

CGFloat JDUT = ( 2440587.5000 + (millis / 86400000) );
NSLog(@"JDUT: %f", JDUT);
```

result JDUT: **2,458,840.394811**